# having php code inside an array string

Tags: php, arrays

im working with arrays and replacing certain values with html code so it gets outputed properly, but stays neat and html-free when being stored. following is the dumbed down code.

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.php';
$replace = array('<1>','<2>');
$this = array("<div class=\"post\"><p>",
    "</p></div>"
    );
str_replace($replace,$this,$file);
?>
```

problem i have is that i need some php inserted as well, so that only a user with admin privileges will see output. i have tried putting the php into the $this array however it doesnt get processed as php. i would need an

```
if ($userIsAdmin) {
```

before the

```
<div>
```

and

```
}
```

after the

```
</div>
```

any suggestions? thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do what you're asking for. Give us a better example of what you're trying to achieve and we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: sorry thought i was pretty clear, but to summarize i need an if statement inside the array. any way i try to insert it in the array, it does not get processed as php.

Comment: Yes, you can't do that. You cannot have an if statement inside an array. You should have the conditional statement outside and only carry out certain actions if they are an admin.

Comment: cuz my actual code has 8 arrays to replace, so i would need an if logged in, replace all 8 arrays in this manner, else replace them in another manner? this feels bloated, having practically the same code copy pasted, except for a minor differece. i was hoping there would be a more practical way

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the unprocessed php code, store it to a variable `$code` and the evaluate it:

```
$result = eval("?>" . $code . "<?");
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea. The code will be unclear and you can introduce a lot of security issues.

Comment: i just ended up having two different $this arrays, one with what admin should see, the other without then an if user is admin use $this1 else use $this2 not very nice, but seems to be only way